# Does replacing int with short help the performance in CUDA

Tags: memory, cuda

assume that we have enough global memory. Does replacing `int` with `short` improve the performance in CUDA? (like `short` saves the usage of shared memory, registers, etc)

Advices are welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `short` in shared memory will most likely **reduce** performance due to bank-conflicts, until you use `short2`.

Also, as far as I know, all registers on GPU are 32-bit, so it's unlikely that using `short` would reduce register usage.

Comment: Yes I think that the registers being 32 bit is the limiting factors.

Answer (score 4):

Depends:

If your program is memory bound then **Yes** transferring the input as shorts could be beneficial.

If your kernel is computation bound is more likely to be **No** because the kernel have to do an extra operation to convert from short to int and then back to short each time.

Answer (score 1):

Tesla-class hardware (SM 1.x) has surprisingly rich support for "half registers," so you might get some mileage from using short instead of int on those platforms.  You can confirm by using cuobjdump to look at the microcode in the cubin. But Fermi removed that support.

With SM 2.1, NVIDIA added support for "video" instructions that implement 32-bit-wide SIMD operations on 32-bit registers - see section 8.7.9 of the PTX 2.1 spec.

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_1/toolkit/docs/ptx_isa_2.1.pdf